# Update/Insert SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a program written in C# with a SQL Server database. In the database there is a table (`ProcessData`) with 3 columns: `ID` (PK, auto-ID), `Start` (DateTime), `End` (DateTime).

There are also a lot of threads which will be inserting new rows into the database table (`ProcessData`) every few minutes/seconds.

I want to insert at the beginning only the ID and the Start columns, and after few minutes/seconds ACCORDING TO THE ID, add the End column.

How can I do that?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to insert a new row, capture the newly created ID, and later on update the row??

Something like this

```
DECLARE @NewID INT

INSERT INTO dbo.tblProcessData(Start) VALUES (@Start)
SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and later on:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblProcessData 
SET End = @End 
WHERE ID = @NewID
```

Is that what you're looking for??

Answer (score 0):

Unless I’m missing something you could just do one insert statement at the start

```
INSERT INTO tblProcessData (Start) VALUES (@Start)
```

Then later an update statement

```
UPDATE tblProcessData SET End=@End WHERE ID=@ID
```

There are many ways to skin a cat but that is one of the T-SQL ways

Comment: Ok, than the all mighty question: How to get the ID from an insert statement?

Comment: SCOPE_IDENDITY () function contains the last inserted ID of a scope. Select for it ;)

Comment: The answer left by marc_s is a more complete version of mine which includes returning the ID etc

Answer (score 0):

Your Table 
**ProcessData** Contains

```
ID(PK, auto-ID)
Start(DateTime)
End(DateTime)
```

Query

```
Insert Into ProcessData(Start) values (your value)

After some time

Update ProcessData Set End=(your value) where ID= (your ID)
```